# interaction.options.getString is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to code a MusicBot for Discord in discord.js but when i try to execute the play command I always get interaction.options.getString is not a function. I searched in the Internet for this error couldn't find anything.

My Code:

```
const { QueryType, useMainPlayer, useQueue } = require("discord-player");
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "play",
  description: "play a song!",
  voiceChannel: true,
  options: [
    {
      name: "song",
      description: "the song you want to play",
      type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
      required: true,
    },
  ],

  callback: async (interaction, client) => {
    const player = useMainPlayer();
    const song = interaction.options.getString("play");
};
```

I also tried the interaction.options.get command but doesn't work either.

Comment: That should depend on what you are passing in interaction. Where is callback being used?